# Internal Server Error using Google API on PHP

Tags: php, curl, plesk

Running this code on Godaddy, Plesk account returns 'Internal Server Error'. Should I make any changes to code or any configuration to run this code?

Code ran perfectly in easyphp local server. Please help. Thank you.

```
    sendPush($to,$title,$message);

    function sendPush($to,$title,$message)
    {
        // API access key from Google API's Console
        // replace API
        define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AIzlkplhm-KrtLlR-p-Mg');
        $registrationIds = array($to);
        $msg = array
        (
        'message' => $message,
        'title' => $title,
        'vibrate' => 1,
        'sound' => 1

        // you can also add images, additionalData
        );
        $fields = array
        (
        'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
        'data' => $msg
        );
        $headers = array
        (
        'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
        $result = curl_exec($ch );
        curl_close( $ch );
        echo $result;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error in the server log?

Comment: @Jeff This is what I see in server log. Im not sure if it is the right log.

2016-04-08 05:32:56 W3SVC930 SG2NWVPWEB019 182.50.132.41 GET /server_files/Test.php - 80 - 106.67.4.200 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/49.0.2623.87+Safari/537.36+OPR/36.0.2130.46 - - timetoter.com 500 0 0 1631 422 4093